# How to accumulate NSTimer values

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I have a timer that I start and stop multiple times.  How do I accumulate the values once the timer has stopped each time?

Comment: What warrants the "down-vote"?  I did the research (the answer is not in Google or on SO), and because of that, I feel it is useful to others.

Comment: Because you haven't defined what you mean by 'values' and you havent posted any code in your question? You also haven't said what you've tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the timer is started note the start time. Whenever the timer fires add the difference between the current time and the start time to your total. Then reset the start time to the current time. When the timer is stopped, you either add the difference between the current time and start time to the total or don't depending on your application, but you don't reset the start time. When the timer is restarted, don't add anything to the total, but reset the start time.

So something like this:

```
startTime = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow]; // This is an NSDate* in your class
```

Then when your timer fires:

```
NSDate* currentTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow];
accumulatedTime += [currentTime timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime]; // accumulatedTime is an NSTimeInterval in your class
[startTime release];
startTime = [currentTime retain];
```

etc.

Comment: Hmmm... not really what I was looking for... the timer can be started, paused and stopped.  I know that this code will give me the timer interval:  NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: timeInterval];

My question is: how do I accumulate this?  Use another NSDate object?

Comment: Yes, see my changes above. I've added some code to make it clearer.

Comment: user1118321:  I'm going to accept your answer, not so much for the code above, but for finding the 1/10th of a second issue.  Thank you so much for saving me much egg on my face! (My code works, and I'm going to go with it because it fits with the supporting code.)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... here is how I did it:

```
NSTimeInterval *accumulatedTime;
accumulatedTime += 1.0;  //  add one second
```

This is assuming of course that you have the supporting code to start, pause and stop the timer.

Comment: This just adds 1/10th of a second to your counter. It doesn't actually use the current time, so it could lead to inaccuracies. Your timer might not actually fire exactly on every 10th of a second, for example, depending on what else your app is doing.

Comment: RATS!  I didn't think of that... let me try your code and I'll get back to you... thank you for clarifying your answer too! :D